# Creating Co Administrator for Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I have gone through steps mentioned in the below url

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456328.aspx

It says that 
"In Email Address, type a valid Windows Live ID or corporate email address for the new co-administrator."

By corporate email address what they mean, is it any mail id from the same domain which is being used to login on the portal or something else?

Comment: I do't think so and I don't know what 'corporate email address' mean. As far as I know, you have to use Live ID to sign in Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a live id unless you are located on a domain that is configured to federate azure identity for your organization.  For most users, a registered live id is what they need.